# EF Code First Не работает lazy loading для новой сущности

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Модель строится на основе EF 4.2 Code First.Ошибка происходит в следующем участке кода:

```
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket()
                {
                    Id=0,
                    Caption=caption,
                    CreatedDate=DateTime.Now,
                    MustBeClosedDate=mustBeClosedDate,
                    Status="Новая",
                    InitiatorId=initiatorId,
                    ResponsibleId=responsibleId,
                    Priority=priority,
                    TicketType=type,
                    HDId=authorId,
                    HtmlBody=bodyHtml,
                    TextBody=bodyHtml.RemoveTags()
                };

                repository.Add(ticket);
                SaveTicket(ticket);
```

После сохранения у новой сущности свойство Responsible null. Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо. Сама модель:

```
    public class Ticket
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? MustBeClosedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FactClosedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Priority { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string TicketType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AssignedProject")]
        public long? ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Initiator")]
        public int InitiatorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("HD")]
        public int HDId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Responsible")]
        public int ResponsibleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string TextBody { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string HtmlBody { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AssignedTickets")]
        public virtual HDUser Responsible { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("CreatedTickets")]
        public virtual HDUser HD { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("MonitoredTickets")]
        public virtual HDUser Initiator { get; set; }

        public virtual Project AssignedProject { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AssignedTicket")]
        public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("AssignedTicket")]
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

аттрибут ForeignKey назначается на свойтсов объекта. То есть, в вашем случае, следует это использовать как:

```
public int ResponsibleId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ResponsibleId")]
[InverseProperty("AssignedTickets")]
public virtual HDUser Responsible { get; set; }
```

А метод .Add() порождает SQL операцию INSERT и только. Я бы после инсерта просто запрашивал бы обновленный контекст из репозитория, используя FirstOrDefault(). Тогда Lazy будет работать.